# minimum number of points to cover all the ranges

Tags: algorithm

We are given n number of ranges and we need to place minimum number of points so that each range contains atleast 1 point in it.
I know this question has already been asked on this site but I am trying to further optimise it
Below is my algorithm

1.First I will do some preprocessing and for each end point I will store its starting point.To maintain uniqueness I will also consider the index.

2.Next I will initialise an array which will be store the numbers we need to mark (which are our answer). Initialise it with [0]

3.Next I will sort all the end points and iterate through it. For each end point I will check if its starting point has come before or after the last marked point

a. If the starting point has come before the last marked point that means the range corrosponding to the current end point already contains the last visited point ans so no need to mark the current end point

b. If instead the starting point has come after(say last marked point is 5 and the starting point is 7) then this range doesn't yet contain a number in it and we will mark this point and insert it in the array.

Now as the array which we generating is already sorted so we can just compare with the last element of the array. I also took care of ranges whose lower and upper bound are same. I counted them separately and I am not considering them again

But the above algorithm is not working.

What could be wrong
Here is my python 3 code.

```
from collections import defaultdict
d=defaultdict(lambda:0)

n=int(input())
a=[]
ranges=[]
for i in range(n):
    s,e=[int(i) for i in input().split()]
    ranges.append([s,e])
    d[(i,e)]=s
    a.extend([(s,i,'s'),(e,i,'e')])

final=[0]
ans=0
a.sort(key=lambda a:a[0])

for time,ind,type in a:
    if type=='e' and d[(ind,time)]==time:
        if final[-1]<time:
            final.append(time)
            ans+=1
    elif type=='e':
        if final[-1]<d[(ind,time)] and final[-1]<time:
            final.append(time)
            ans+=1

print(ans)
for e in final[1:]:
    print(e,end=' ')
```

Comment: Voting to close, since this is a duplicate.  The other question doesn't have a simple implementation, though, so I'll add one.  You should look there, because most of the code you've written here is unnecessary -- you don't need a dict, you don't need to sort the start points (in fact you go through some trouble to ignore them explicitly,), etc.

Comment: Closed as duplicate. If you're looking to specifically find out what's wrong with your code, the best way forward is probably to debug it - see [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: is my algorithm wrong or what. I mentioned in the very beginning that it has been asked before and I couldn't uderstand the answer that's why I am asking it again. I want a discussion with the algo I proposed

Comment: Ah, you said you were trying to optimize, not debug, which I why I wrote you some nice fast code in the other question.  The algorithm you wrote in text works fine.  If the code is broken then you should look at the values of variables at various points and see where it deviates from your expectations. You wrote the code, so you should know what it's supposed to get and do on every line.  By asking us to just look at the code and tell you what's wrong with it, you're asking us to solve a problem that is *way* harder than the one you have to solve, because we don't know the author's intent.